# MATLAB: How to keep the terminal state after using unix() command?

Tags: linux, matlab, unix

After using `unix` command, Matlab runs the script and closes the terminal, clearing all the variables in terminal. In this simplified example, if I run:

```
[status1,cmdout1]=unix('NUM=100'); %//create variable NUM and assign value 100 to it
[status2,cmdout2]=unix('echo $NUM'); %//display variable value
```

both commands would run successfully, but `cmdout2` would be an empty string. To mitigate this, I can run both commands in a single `unix` block, like:

```
[status,cmdout]=unix('NUM=100;echo $NUM');
```

so after assigning `100` to `NUM`, the terminal is not closed and I will see `100` in `cmdout`. However, for my application it is not possible as some intermediate processing in Matlab is needed. So, the question is, how to preserve terminal and all the variables after running `unix` command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MATLAB executes external commands in the environment of the original `matlab` process. What you could try is using `setenv` to modify the matlab environment.

```
>> setenv('NUM','100');
>> [status,cmdout] = unix('echo $NUM')
status = 0
cmdout = 100
```

All the subsequent commands would also be able to see the new value of the `NUM` variable.